# Lenovo Z50 with 8.1 preinstalled

Tags: windows-8.1

My laptop create shotcut when I connected to pendrive or any other data.when I copying something to my laptop a shortcut file is created

Comment: Thanks for sharing.  Do you have some kind of problem or question?

Answer (score 1):

This happens due to malware, it only can remove by licenced antivirus software and if you have created system restore point before the malwares enter in your system, then you can go to this resore point it will remove the malware from ypur pc.